# Uploading file to blob container & add a record to db reliably

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

We need our API to upload a file to azure blob container and once uploaded, a record needs to be inserted into the db with some metadata and url pointing to the file.

We need to do it in a reliable way so that we don't get db entries without corresponding files in blob storage nor that we have orphan files in storage without corresponding db entries.

The only way i can think of doing it reliably is to have API upload the file into the container and set metadata on the blob item itself. After that, have a background process (Azure Function triggered by new blob entry) that would get metadata from a newly created blob item and write it to db.

Is there any simplier or more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

i think a trigger mechanism like you've described would work well. if the starting point is the file upload then technically a file could always exist without a db record, but the db record could never exist without a file. therefore you could write a compensation mechanism to scan all files within x time and make sure they all have db records if you're really worried about things falling through the cracks

Comment: well, its pretty much all the same for me which comes first. what i need to end up with is an "entry" on both sides. Since the user uploads both at the same time (file and some metadata), i see no way of starting with db record unless i want to store file into blob column in db (which i definitely don't).